# 'No Layers in Render Result' issue. Missing layers window in UV Editor

Tags: layers, uv-image-editor

I've installed the newest Blender version (2.76 b) lately and found out that the layers window in *UV Editor* is missing. I can't choose the slot for render. How to fix it?
[image]

EDIT: As @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ suggested I've rendered an image using full render and layers window appears, but as you can see in a .gif below I have to press <kbd>J</kbd> until I display the full render result to select the desired layer. When I display the *OpenGL* viewport render, the layers window is not present. Is it a matter of changes in new version or there is a setting in *User Preferences* to fix it?
[image]

Comment: That is very odd. This works as expected for me.

Comment: Have you tried to render anything yet? If not it won't show up.

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ it worked, but only for full render (F12), the open GL viewport render doesn't have the layers selection option (please see the edit of my question).

Comment: Did this ever work? (awesome character BTW)

Comment: Yes, it worked well in previous version. No matter if you rendered using F12 or openGL the layers window were available. Thanks BTW:).

Comment: I would report that as a bug - at the very least the slots menu should not disappear. This is a regression as up to 2.74 it works as expected while 2.75 and 2.76 the menus go missing.

Comment: @sambler good point, this is the regression according to previous versions. I'll report it as a bug soon.

Comment: @sambler Bug report posted.